# Best way to search multiple solr core

Tags: java, solr, distributed-computing, solrj

I'm developing an application that serves as a client for solr. I have to do a multi-core search where the fields are exactly the same. I do not know the best way to implement it. I'm using solrj in java.
What would be best to use Distributed Search from solr or search on each separate core using threads on the application side?

Example

```
http://XXXX:8983/solr/core1
http://XXXX:8983/solr/core2
http://XXXX:8983/solr/core3
http://XXXX:8983/solr/core4
```

The fields in each core are the same.

I want to search efficiently search in all colors with a resulting result-set.

[Solr UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFKAR.png)

At this moment I have 26 cores, the largest have
Num Docs: 4677529
Size: 56.7 GB

The others have similar values. The number of cores tends to increase.

Thanks

Comment: Are the cores on the same Solr instance or distributed between more instances?

Comment: All the cores are based on the same identical schema and configuration?

Comment: yes, both questions

Comment: Have you Solr configured in SolrCloud mode, i.e. all the nodes connected to a Zookeeper ensemble which share the cluster configuration?

Comment: No, I do not have the cloud configured. I edited the post by adding an image of my solr.

Comment: How big are your indexes? How many documents ?

Comment: @freedev edit post

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understand from question and comments your scenario is perfect for SolrCloud, which is the name of a configuration that enables a set of new distributed capabilities in Solr.

A collection is a complete logical index that could be physically distributed across more Solr instances.

When you have to submit a query to your collection all you have to do is refer to the collection like previously you did with your cores. The SolrJ client should be built in a different manner, you have to specify the zookeeper connection string, use the `CloudSolrClient` and specify the default collection.

```
String zkHostString = "zkServerA:2181,zkServerB:2181,zkServerC:2181/solr";
CloudSolrClient solr = new CloudSolrClient.Builder().withZkHost(zkHostString).build();
solr.setDefaultCollection("collectionName");
```

This let you to the following options:

1. Your configuration is already a SolrCloud environment but didn't know anything about. Let's check if your Solr admin (taken from of one of your Solr Instances) and see if there is "Cloud" menu in the left menu. See the attached image

   [image: Solr Admin - Cloud Menu]

In this case, have a look at Cloud menu, this will show you the network topology of your Cluster and the name of the collection to use in your SolrJ implementation. See the attached image:

[image: Solr Cloud topology]

2. In case the "Cloud" menu is missing (image 1). You should move your existing cores from a standalone Solr configuration to SolrCloud.

To be clear you cannot switch your existing Solr instances from standalone to SolrCloud. The simplest way I would suggest is create a new SolrCloud cluster and reindex all your cores. I also suggest to have a look at [Solr terminology in a SolrCloud configuration](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrTerminology).

In the following lines are the steps to create a SolrCloud:

- create a [Zookeeper ensemble](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Setting+Up+an+External+ZooKeeper+Ensemble)
- create one or more Solr instances and start them in SolrCloud mode (i.e. specifying the zookeeper connection string parameter `-z zk-node1:2181,zk-node2:2181,zk-node3:2181` at Solr start)
- upload your Solr collection configuration to Zookeeper (use [Solr zkcli.sh tool](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Command+Line+Utilities))
- create your collection - [Collection API - create a collection](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Collections+API#CollectionsAPI-CREATE:CreateaCollection)

Now you can start to move (reindex) your documents into the new brand collection you have created.

From the size and the number of documents you're re-indexing you have to create a number of shards in order to split the collection across your SolrCloud instances.

I strongly suggest to make practice with a playground, for example start a recent version of Solr (6.x) with the `-cloud -e cloud` parameter. This would start more Solr instances and a zookeeper standalone all on the same server, but consider this just as a toy to see how the things work.

Comment: very detailed explanation...very much appreciated the efforts on it...+1

Answer (score 0):

if all the cores have the same config, and you are worried with efficiency etc, it would make more sense to have this setup under Solrcloud.

- you can have all the data under a single collection and then sharded
- or you can have your data partitioned into multiple different collections (that can be sharded as well, of course). For instance it is typical to have monthly collections for logs data.
- then you have an alias that points to all your collections
- on the client side, you just query the alias, and all is transparent for you, all needed collections are hit, search is distributed as needed etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change anything (i.e. these are cores that usually live and behave separate from other cores) and it's a small, contained task (i.e. not something you want to scale further in the future), you can [use the explicit sharding support](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Distributed+Search+with+Index+Sharding) in Solr to query all the cores at the same time. This assumes that the documents are roughly evenly distributed across cores, as the scores are calculated locally before being aggregated in the node you're querying.